# Как правильно в данном предложении: «не далеко» или «недалеко»?

Tags: грамматика

*Земляне будущего ушли не( )далеко в своем техническом прогрессе от нашей современной Земли.*

Как правильно и почему?

Answer (score 1):

И всё же это не объяснение - "чаще используется".
Есть точная логика передачи того, или иного смысла.

Самое общее определение.
Частица "не" пишется с прилагательным слитно, если и смысл фразы утверждает полностью противоположное качество прилагательного.
Интересная - неинтересная) полностью противоположное качество).
Эта книга неинтересная.
Частица "не" пишется с прилагательным раздельно, если смысл фразы отрицает прямое качество прилагательного, уточняя или не уточняя наличие иного.
Интересная - не интересная. (Без уточнения).
Эта книга не интересная, а посредственная. (с уточнением).

Для автора фразы есть три способа быстрой проверки, какой смысл он вкладывает - утверждение противоположного качества, или отрицание прямого качества.

1. Определение смысла через вставку наречия.

Мысленно вставить во фразу перед "не" и после "не" наречие, особенно обозначающее какую-нибудь меру, например "совсем".
Эта книга совсем неинтересная.
Эта книга не совсем интересная.
Определиться автору, какой из этих вариантов больше подходит под передаваемый смысл. Там, где "совсем" между "не" и прилагательным точнее передаёт вкладываемый автором смысл, так "не" пишется раздельно с прилагательным и по смыслу является отрицанием положительного качества. 
Эта книга не интересная.
Если же наречие "совсем" перед "не" только обостряет передаваемый автором смысл, то "не с прилагательным" пишется слитно и по смыслу является утверждением отрицательного качества.

2. Определение смысла через вариабельное место глагола, в том числе присутствующего неявно. 
   Эта книга (есть) неинтересная.
   Эта книга (есть) не интересная.

Смысл утверждения противоположного качества ставит глагол присваивания (есть) только перед "не", а поставленный поле него искажает передаваемый смысл. Отрицание же прямого качества перестановка глагола на место после "не", только обостряет этот смысл, как с последующим уточнением, так и без уточнения иного качества.
Эта книга (есть) неинтересная. - только утверждение противоположного качества.
Эта книга не (есть) интересная. - отрицание прямого качества без уточнения иного.
Эта книга не (есть) интересная, а(есть) посредственная. - отрицание прямого качества с уточнением иного.

3. Определение через ударение в выразительной речи.

Если проговаривать предложение артистически выразительно, то при слитном написании и утверждении противоположного качества смысл не позволяет в речи ставить ударение на "нЕ" и делать паузу между "не" и прилагательным.
Нет такого слова "нЕинтересная". Ударение всегда -  "неинтерЕсная".
Если же смысл отрицательного качества, то ударение на "нЕ"  и некоторая разделительная пауза между "не" и прилагательным делает смысл только ещё выразительнее.
Эта книга нЕ ... интересная.

Самый простой и быстрый для использования автором в проверке передаваемого смысла фразы - это последний вариант, через максимально выразительное проговаривание фразы.

Comment: filosa, боюсь вам придется привести ваш ответ в соответствие  правилам ресурса. Во-первых, дайте, пожалуйста, конкретный ответ на конкретный вопрос. Во-вторых, у вас достаточно много несамочевидной информации. Нужны ссылки на источники.

Comment: Если настолько разжёванная логика не доходит, то ссылки на большие учебники логики не помогут. Тогда передавайте смысл написанного приблизительно, как чаще встречается у других, а не настолько утончённо, насколько позволяют возможности языка.

Answer (score 0):

***Земляне будущего ушли недалеко в своем техническом прогрессе от нашей современной Земли.***

Оба варианта возможны, на чаще используется слитное написание (62:9 в Нацкорпусе).

Почему? По смыслу варианты мало отличаются, поэтому использовать отрицательную конструкцию нет особой причины (нет усиления, противопоставления или других причин).

Пример отрицательного предложения (при наличии вопросительной частицы ЛИ):  *Не далеко ли  в сторону ушли мы от наших идеалов?*

Примеры: *Коли так, то, значит, мы **недалеко ушли** от пчелы и наша вековая культура ― это не в коня корм. Если разобраться, тут мы от Африки **недалеко ушли**. Наверное, сами по уровню воспитания недалеко ушли.*

*Российское кино оказалось глубоко там же, где иностранное. Такого бреда я мог ждать только от Америки, но, как вышло, наши тоже **не далеко ушли**!*